# Change alert box font size in Firefox 15

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a demo I am doing of a learn to code site for high school students (http://codeavengers.com/javascript) with media present. The Prime Minister will be writing his first line of code which is essentially hello world in an alert box.

I would like to use the standard Firefox alert box, but would like to increase the font size dramatically so everyone can see.

Is there an easy way (e.g. modifying a browser setting or config file) to increase the font size of the standard alert box.

If this can not be done easily in Firefox, is there an easy way in Chrome, Opera or Safari?

Comment: Set the resolution of the screen really low

Comment: Sorry... changed the link to go straight to the JavaScript lesson I am referring to in the question

Comment: The screen resolution is what I suggested, but the people doing the presentation don't want to do that... because they will have some other slide presentation on the screen immediately before switching to my app. So will not be time to change the res.

Comment: Not much you can change about the look of the `alert()`

Comment: I guess I could dive into Firefox source code, but no doubt it would be easier to just use a custom alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few Firefox addons that allow you to change the system fonts.
I used https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/theme-font-size-changer/?src=search

Answer (score 1):

if you use windows 7, press 'win' + '+' to bring up magnifier.

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry, too long to reasonably leave as a comment.)

If, for that first lesson or so, you do *not* need `window.alert` to block, you could replace the `window.alert` function with one of your own to display the string in a floating div.

There is no way I know of to make this block, so it has limited use.

To rewrite the function you could either

- Copy off the web page locally and introduce a bit of your own Javascript.

or

- Use a userscript/GreaseMonkey script to replace the function.

Might be enough to squeak you by.

Comment: Yes I do need it to block, otherwise the rest of the code that checks correctness, and gives feedback will not work correctly. Thanks for the suggestion!